# Can someone help me identify this queen ant?

Tags: species-identification, ant

I found this queen ant near a river on the 14 july in Braga-Portugal, it was on a river bank, and it measures around 8 mm. Can someone help me identifying the species? thank you for your time :)

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]
[image: 8]

Answer (score 1):

The small space between the thorax and the abdomen indicates this queen has only one petiole segment (no post-petiole). The large size and absence of an elongated first abdominal segment indicates the subfamily Formicinae. The morphological features necessary to go further with a formal identification are not visible, but from the general aspect of the ant it is likely to be a *Lasius* or a *Formica*.

See ref below:

> Seifert, Bernhard. Die Ameisen Mittel-und Nordeuropas. Lutra Verlag-u.
>   Vertriebsges., 2007.